# Craft redirect loop after logging in

Tags: control-panel, redirect, loop

I'm experiencing weird cookie/redirect issues after logging in the admin/cp. Keeps redirecting to / (even on /) untill I've deleted my cookies.

Clean download/install, no errors occured. I have no idea what to check:

- clean download of latest version 2.4.2700, no changes
- different domain/hosting tested, still redirect occurs
- different browsers tested, same results

Pulling my hair out here, any suggestions/ideas?

-- edit
It has to be a cookie/session related issue, but all paths are 'normal'. Using CentOS with cPanel, all up to date

Comment: Have you made changes to the htaccess file?

Comment: No, we even removed the .htaccess to make sure that wasn't the issue. Using the index.php gives no other result unfortunately :(

Comment: Are you using any caching like Varnish/Cloudflare/PHP opcache/APC/etc?

Comment: Nope, no caching server/service is being used

Comment: Did this happen from initially installing?  If not could it be a plugin dashboard widget issue?

Comment: If you want to send some CP/FTP credentials over to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can take a stab at it and update here with any results.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) rule tripping up the request and causing an infinite redirect loop.

I don't know which rule it was exactly, but disabling ModSecurity resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you Brad, it appears to have triggered rules: `973337: XSS Filter - Category 2: Event Handler Vector` and `981246: Detects basic SQL authentication bypass attempts 3/3`. I have reported this to cPanel for wrongly triggering with Craft.

Comment: `ModSec` is such a pain. Rule `981243: Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2` has begun causing the redirect issue as well.

Comment: IMO things like ModSec and Suhosin are generally more pain than they're worth.

Comment: Agreed. Disabled it's SQL Injection filters, one more problem out of it, and it's being nuked.